How to extract or capture the value from stdout_lines of an Ansible playbook?
I am looking for help to extract or capture the free MB value from the stdout_lines of an Ansible playbook execution and use that value as a criteria to proceed further in the playbook.
My task output is :
ok: [Host1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "commands": [
                "show file systems | inc flash:"
            ],
            "interval": 1,
            "match": "all",
            "retries": 10,
            "wait_for": null
        }
    },
    "stdout": [
        "*     1707192   (1.6 GB)        603744 (589.6 MB)      flash     rw  flash:"
    ],
    "stdout_lines": [
        [
            "*     1707192   (1.6 GB)        603744 (589.6 MB)      flash     rw  flash:"
        ]
    ]
}

I tried to use
- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ disk_space.stdout_lines | regex_findall('\\b([0-9]{1,4}\\.\\d+)\\s+MB.*flash:$') }}"

But I always get an empty output:
ok: [Host1] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "my_var": []
    },
    "changed": false
}

I would like to capture 589.6 value from the output and assign it to variable to be used in my further play.

Can you provide your task as well a description about the remote system? Maybe there are already options to get the ouput in a simpler or formatted way, or even dedicated modules.

An other possible approach is shown in the following minimal example playbook
---
- name: Cisco 'show file systems'
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    disk_space:
      stdout: "*     1707192   (1.6 GB)        603744 (589.6 MB)      flash     rw  flash:"
      stdout_lines:
        - "*     1707192   (1.6 GB)        603744 (589.6 MB)      flash     rw  flash:"

  tasks:

  - name: Show stdout with data cleansing
    debug:
      msg: "{{ disk_space.stdout | regex_replace('  *', ' ') }}"

  - name: Show value of 4th column in KB
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ( disk_space.stdout | regex_replace('  *', ' ') | split(' ') )[4] }} KB"

  - name: Show value of 4th column in MB
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ( disk_space.stdout | regex_replace('  *', ' ') | split(' ') )[4] | int / 1024 }} MB"

resulting into an output of
TASK [Show stdout with data cleansing] **********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '* 1707192 (1.6 GB) 603744 (589.6 MB) flash rw flash:'

TASK [Show value of 4th column in KB] ***********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 603744 KB

TASK [Show value of 4th column in MB] ***********************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 589.59375 MB

Or even
  - name: Show value of 5th column after cleansing
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ( result.stdout | regex_replace('  *', ' ') | replace('(', '') | replace(')', '') | split(' ') )[5] }}"

with result of
TASK [Show value of 5th column] ****************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '589.6'


Hello @U880D ,
Thank you so much for your help !! This worked and I get the exact value. This method is definitely something I can use in my other use cases as well. However, I was still trying to extract the value using regex_findall.
Thank you !!

Just answering the regex part of the question.
The expression written like this
\\b([0-9]{1,4}\\.\\d+)\\s+MB.*flash:$

and parsed as
\b([0-9]{1,4}\.\d+)\s+MB.*flash:$

means "the line must end with flash:, but it ends like with flash:"
The solution is simple - add the character just before the dollar sign
\b([0-9]{1,4}\.\d+)\s+MB.*flash:"$

Not sure if that should be escaped or encoded in any specific way in your case.

Hello Sam,
Thank you so much for looking into this. I did made the change you have suggested, but still it gives me empty list as output.
- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ disk_space.stdout_lines | regex_findall('\\b([0-9]{1,4}\\.\\d+)\\s+MB.*flash:\"$') }}"

Output is :
ok: [ALM-DUT-MGT-P01-05] => {
"ansible_facts": {
"my_var": []
},
"changed": false
}
